# Отображение и выбор результатов поиска

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть алгоритм поиска, который возвращает `List<string>` с путями к найденным файлам. Хочется создать окно, в которое будет передаваться результаты и в котором будут создаваться необходимое количество label'ов с путями с кнопки справа от них, по нажатию на одну из которых окно будет закрываться, а выбранный результат помещаться в переменную.
Сейчас застрял на динамическом создании label'ов, подскажите как это лучше сделать(чем понятнее, тем лучше) или какие еще варианты можно для этого использовать?

Comment: Не оч понятно, что вы хотите получить и что пробовали. Но вот поглядите ссылки [тыц](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/) и [тыц](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например с помощью `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Paths}"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel Margin="0,2">
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Выбрать"
                        Command="{Binding DataCintext.SelectCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

где `Paths` - ваш список, `SelectCommand` - команда, которая размещена в главной VM окна, принимает путь в параметре и записывает его в нужную переменную

Comment: Если с списком я разобрался, то с SelectCommand не могу, подсобите кодом, который будет выводить это в переменную.

Comment: Дополню ответ позже. Если вы пока не вникали в mvvm, то можете просто подписаться на Click по кнопке и получить выбранный пусть так: `string path = (sender as Button).DataContext as string;` Тогда Comnand и CommandParameter уберите из разметки

Comment: работает, спасибо.